# self join with a self-referring condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join

What I want to do is to get all records that have almost exact duplicates except that duplicates don't have an extra char at the beginning of 'name'

this is my sql query:

```
select * from tags as spaced inner join tags as not_spaced on not_spaced.name = substring(spaced.name, 2);
```

also I tried:

```
 select * from tags as spaced where (select count(*) from tags as not_spaced where not_spaced.name = substring(spaced.name, 2)) > 0;
```

What I'm getting is... the SQL connection stops responding.
Thanks!

p.s. Sorry I haven't mentioned that the only field I need is name. All other fields are insignificant (if present).

Comment: How large is your table and what DB are you using? Self-joins could be very time-consuming...

Comment: it is stock mysql and the table is 21269 records long
so, should i just wait?

Comment: i'm an sql novice, so could you tell me whether the queries are wrongly constructed or they are just 'heavy'?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

`select` *all potentially duplicated fields **except** name* `, name`

```
from tags union all
```

`select` *all potentially duplicated fields **except** name* `, substring(name, 2) name`

```
from tags
```

`group by` *all potentially duplicated fields **including** name*

```
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If the tables are very large, make an `index` on `name` and `substring(name,2)` **to make it faster**:

```
select t1.* from tags t1
inner join tags t2 on t1.name = substring(t2.name, 2)
```

Comment: The OP isn't querying the logic as such, the OP is querying why...  `the SQL connection stops responding.`

Comment: @Dems: Read where he wrote: "What I want to do...". The connection stops responding because the query takes too long, that's obvious.

Comment: @Dems I have a solution (`indexes`) on my answer.

Comment: Nice!  Assuming the OP's brand of SQL will allow that index :)

Answer (score 0):

Even with an Index, your query will require every record in `spaced` to be checked against every record in `tags`.

If each table has 1,000 records, that's 1,000,000 combinations.

You may be better off creating a temporary table with just two fields `spaced.id, substring(t2.name, 2) as shortname`, then index the shortname field.  Joining on that temporary and indexed table will be much much faster.

Comment: With 21,269 records, it's processing 452,370,361 comparisons.   With an indexed temporary holding table, it will be 21,269 index seeks.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the DB, how the tables are indexed, etc, it's just trying different things until one gets better optimized...

Here is another query you can try:

```
SELECT name, count(*) c FROM (
    SELECT name FROM tags
    UNION ALL
    SELECT substring(name, 2) AS name FROM tags
) AS t
GROUP BY name
```